# How do I minimize images when I make my screen smaller?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, resize

I have a div class full of images. When my screen is at full size, I have them positioned exactly where I want them. But if I start minimizing the screen a little bit, the images begin to overlap with each other and stay the same size. How can I get my images to remain in the same position relative to each other and reduce in size when I begin to minimize my screen?

I understand that if my images are sized at 100%, then they will be able to minimize correctly when minimized. However, the images I am using are too big which is why I set their sizes manually. Even if they were the correct sizes, I still want them to remain in the same place relative to each other. To illustrate what I am aiming for, here is a website that will minimize and position their images correctly when the screen is minimized: https://kuon.space/#top

```css
/* Planets Styles */

.parallax {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 300px; /* changed from 300px */
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.center-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.surrounding-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* positions of surrounding stars */

.star-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
}

.star-image:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 27%;
  left: 63%;
}

.star-image:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 60%;
  left: 70%;
}

.star-image:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 22%;
  left: 44%;
}

.star-image:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 75%;
  left: 47%;
}

.star-image:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: 45%;
  left: 26%;
}


/* positions of surrounding planets */


/*Orange with Rings*/

.planets-container .surrounding-image:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 55%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
}


/*Purple*/

.planets-container .surrounding-image:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
}


/*Red*/

.planets-container .surrounding-image:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 60%;
  left: 55%;
  bottom: 20%;
}


/*Orange*/

.planets-container .surrounding-image:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: 35%;
  left: 60%;
}


/*Orange and Gray*/

.planets-container .surrounding-image:nth-of-type(6) {
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<section class="parallax">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" class="center-image">

  <div class="stars-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="2" class="star-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="3" class="star-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="-9" class="star-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500">
    <img src="images/planets/hdstar4-removebg-preview.png" data-speed="-5" class="star-image">
  </div>

  <div class="planets-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="5" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="4" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="-4" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="7" class="surrounding-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500" data-speed="2" class="surrounding-image">
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Please update the demo I've created above so it accurately shows your problem.

Comment: I really hope you come up with something good - this is exactly the type of thing that was bugging me over the weekend (not on my own site, but worse -- a commercial site!) where you had to scroll past a series of full size images on a small mobile screen just to find the business hours... which I knew were buried somewhere in the middle of page, surrounded by large pictures. And the pictures were totally useless on such a small screen anyway, as they were so enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Change your image width to another unity than pixels like (% or em or rem), and set the height up to auto.
like this example:

```
.responsive {width: 100%;height: auto;}
```